# Shell Script Issue Running Command Remotely using SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, sh, digital-ocean

I have a deploy script in which I want to clear the cache of my CDN. When I am on the server and run my script everything is fine, however when I SSH in and run only that file (i.e. not actually getting into the server, `cd`ing into the directory and running it) it fails and states the my `doctl` command cannot be found. **This seems to only be an issue with this program over ssh, running systemctl --help works fine.**

Please note that I have installed Digital Ocean's `doctl` using `sudo snap install doctl` and it is there.

Here is the `.sh` file (minus comments):

```
#!/bin/sh
doctl compute cdn flush [MYID]  --files [*]   # static cache
```

So I am not sure what the issue is. Anybody have an idea?

Again, if I get into the server and run the file all works, but here is the SSH command I use that returns the error:

`ssh root@123.45.678.999 "/deploy/clear_digital_ocean_cache.sh"`

And here is the error.

`/deploy/clear_digital_ocean_cache.sh: 10: doctl: not found`

Comment: What directory is this `doctl` command stored in? How is that directory normally added to your command PATH?

Comment: I did just figure out a solution using the absolute path of `doctl`, it is located in `/snap/bin`. I am not actually sure how that directory is added to the command path. Is it possible to add `snap/bin/` to the command path during the `ssh` command?

Comment: Add `PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin` to the beginning of your script.

Comment: Your local `PATH` is not used on the remote host. `ssh` doesn't carry your local environment over to the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one solution was to change the command to be an absolute path inside my `.sh` file like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
/snap/bin/doctl compute cdn flush [MYID]  --files [*]   # static cache
```

I realized that I could run my user commands with `ssh` (like `systemctl`) so it was either change where `doctl` was located (i.e. in the user bin) or ensure that the command was called with an absolute path adding the `/snap/bin/` in front of the command.

Comment: The actual issue is likely that your $PATH is being set differently when run via ssh vs interactively, probably based on the contents of your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.